# How to perform same data augmentation on 2 different image inputs?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to construct a multi-path CNN with 2 image inputs that each enter their own CNN and then the features are concatenated at the end. Right now I have something like this:

features & labels for 1st set of images:
X (has features)
y (labels)

features & labels for 2nd set of images (segmented):
X_2 (has features)
y_2 (has labels)

my code for the augmentation is this:

```
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential()
data_augmentation.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"))
data_augmentation.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2))
data_augmentation.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(height_factor=(.05),
                                                 width_factor=(.05)))
```

and I want the CNN to look something like this:
[CNN model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa2KH.jpg)

both the 1st and 2nd set of images are the same size and are in the same order. The only difference is that the 2nd set are segmented. I want to apply the same data augmentation for both of them. Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried looking for some answers online, but most of the website I found that talk about multi input CNNS didn't use an augmentation layer so I'm stuck.

Comment: You could also write a custom training loop, where you could initiate a new seed in each loop, and pass that seed to the augmentation layers. With a fixed seed, an augmentation layer will perform the same (semi-random) transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(See below for original answer)

I guess [this Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#use_keras_preprocessing_layers) is relevant to data augmentation in Keras. In particular, it mentions [two options to use data augmentation layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#two_options_to_use_the_keras_preprocessing_layers): using it inside `Model` and using it in the `tf.data` pipeline.

Here is a rough (think of it as pseudo-code) example implementation using the second option.

Additionally, my personal preference would be to implement the `Model` described in the question with a [custom `Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing#the_model_class) for flexbility, but perhaps there are ways to do the same with higher-level Keras API.

In the following snippet, a custom `Model` is set up and then the training dataset pipeline. It lacks the exact loading steps but should give a rough idea how to connect the dataset with a custom `Model`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class TwinCNN(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, name="TwinCNN"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        
        self.cnn_for_color = [
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding="same"), 
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding="same"), 
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding="same"), 
        ]  # Some layers
        
        self.cnn_for_segment = [
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same"), 
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same"), 
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same"), 
        ]
        
        self.classifier = [
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                units=4,  # seems there are 4 classes
                activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        ]
    
    def call(self, inputs, training):
        color_image = inputs['color']
        segment_image = inputs['segment']
        
        color_fts = color_image
        for ly in self.cnn_for_color:
            color_fts = ly(color_fts, training=training)
        
        segment_fts = segment_image 
        for ly in self.cnn_for_segment:
            segment_fts = ly(segment_fts, training=training)
        
        concat_fts = tf.concat([color_fts, segment_fts], axis=-1, name='concat_fts')
        
        net = concat_fts
        for ly in self.classifier:
            net = ly(net, training=training)
        return net  # shape Nx4


# Your data augmentation layers
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential()
data_augmentation.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"))
data_augmentation.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2))
data_augmentation.add(tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(height_factor=(.05),
                                                 width_factor=(.05)))

def apply_augment_to_zipped(color_img, segment_img):
    c_color = color_img.shape[-1]  # Number of channels
    concat_img = tf.concat([color_img, segment_img], axis=-1)
    # **For your test/validation dataset, don't use augmentation!**
    img_aug = data_augmentation(concat_img, training=True)
    color_aug = img_aug[..., :c_color]
    segment_aug = img_aug[..., c_color:]
    return color_aug, segment_aug


def turn_image_tuple_to_dict(color_img, segment_img):
    # Put the two images into a dict
    return dict(color=color_img, segment=segment_img)


# Assuming ds_color and ds_segment has the *same* label, so we can take either one
ds_color_images = tf.data.Dataset(...)  # Set up a dataset for color images
ds_labels = tf.data.Dataset(...)  # Set up a dataset for labels
ds_segment_images = tf.data.Dataset(...)  # Set up a dataset for segment images

ds_images = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_color_images, ds_segment_images))  # each entry will be a tuple of 2 images
ds_images_augmented = ds_images.map(apply_augment_to_zipped)
ds_images_augmented = ds_images_augmented.map(turn_image_tuple_to_dict)
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_images_augmented, ds_labels))  # The training set 

# NOTE: for a validation dataset, we should skip the augmentation (i.e. don't call apply_augment_to_zipped)

model = TwinCNN()
# TODO: select an optimizer, 
# TODO: model.compile(optimizer)
model.fit(
    ds_train, # TODO: other training settings
)
```

### Original answer

Since the two datasets are of the same size, one can use

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds1, ds2))
```

to create a dataset where each entry is a pair of images say `(x, x2)`. Then one could do something like

```
ds = ds.map(lambda x, x2: tf.concat([x, x2], axis=-1))
```

To merge `x` and `x2` into a single tensor which fits better for the augmentation layers.

Assuming the number of channels is constant for each `x` (say 3 channels) and each `x2` (say 1 channel), the augmented result can be sliced out afterwards:

```
x_aug = input_tensor[..., :3]
x2_aug = input_tensor[..., 3:4]
```

As a side note, it would be better if the question is more detailed. For example, it would be helpful to provide some code or pseudo-code to explain how exactly the data should flow in the "multi-path CNN" and what sort of data augmentation is being attempted.

Comment: Hi, I made edits to my questions, and I hope I clarified it. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: @TessChan is it the updated answer clearer?

Comment: Glad to know! I would appreciate it a lot if you can mark the answer as accepted.